# red5 media server on windows 10

Tags: red5, red5-recorder, red5-hls-plugin

Help configure red5-recoder media server on localhost.

I had installed red5 media server ([windows installer](https://builds.apache.org/view/M-R/view/OpenMeetings/job/red5-installer/)) on windows 10 with jdk ([jdk installer](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u91-b15/jdk-8u91-windows-x64.exe?AuthParam=1465916758_8dd6e19943ae151cfa852e4860af18e0)).Everything done with no error. After installation I had run install-service.bat from the installation folder. I also started the server manually from "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools\Services".
localhost:5080 is running but when I try to access "http://localhost:5080/installer/" the flash throws error

```
   `Host: localhost
    Trying to connect
    Net status: NetConnection.Connect.Failed
    Trying to connect to war location`
```

Any help would appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That issue should be resolved by updating the war location (where the application wars are stored externally). The details are in this issue report https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/issues/180